# What was the movie reference in Fringe 1x02, "The Same Old Story"?

Tags: fringe

In "The Same Old Story" (*Fringe* Season 1, Episode 2) Dr. Walter Bishop made a reference to a movie in which the last image people saw at their death was frozen in their mind. What was the movie he was talking about?

Comment: You could try asking on movies.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [TV.com](http://www.tv.com/shows/fringe/the-same-old-story-1225411/trivia/), he's referencing a *Jules Verne* book, *The Kip Brothers*.  In 2007, it was released [in English](http://amzn.com/0819567043) for the first time, which implies Walter read it in its original French, or one of the other non-English translations that existed at the time.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the TVTropes page:  http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EyeRemember - really, it could be almost anything on there.

However, due to its relation to "science", I'm going to guess that it was a reference to "[Wild Wild West](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Wild_West)", one of the places where the trope is used.